# How to ignore special characters when using ORDER BY in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, utf-8, replace, sql-order-by, special-characters

I have the following MySQL query that provides data to a Python web page. On the web page, I have a list of song titles, and I want it to be alphabetized ignoring punctuation and spaces. My MySQL database is UTF-8 encoded, and some of the punctuation that needs to be ignored is special characters such as curly apostrophes, etc.

```
SELECT * FROM Tracks\
JOIN Artists USING (ArtistID)\
JOIN Albums USING (AlbumID)\
JOIN Songs USING (SongID)\
ORDER BY UPPER(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(\
REPLACE(SoName, ' ', ''), /* space */\
                        ',', ''), /* comma */\
                        '.', ''), /* period */\
                        ':', ''), /* colon */\
                        ';', ''), /* semicolon */\
                        '!', ''), /* exclamation point */\
                        '?', ''), /* question mark */\
                   '\u201c', ''), /* left curly double quote */\
                   '\u201d', ''), /* right curly double quote */\
                   '\u2019', ''), /* right curly single quote (apostrophe) */\
                   '\u2013', ''), /* n-dash */\
                   '\u2014', ''), /* m-dash */\
                   '\u2026', '') /* ellipsis */), (SongID), UPPER(AlTitle)
```

The `REPLACE` in my query seems to work perfectly for the non-special characters, like the space, comma, period, etc., but it seems to skip over the special characters.

My guess is that the characters need to be written in a different format. I tried the following with no success:
`REPLACE(SoName, '\u2026', '')`
`REPLACE(SoName, u'\2026', '')`
`REPLACE(SoName, 0xE280A6, '')`...

Comment: Thank you your question was my answer, very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MySQL string literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html) do not provide an escape sequence for multi-byte characters.  This has been [a feature request](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10199) for over 7 years and is still awaiting triage: I wouldn't hold my breath that it will be resolved any time soon.

You must either put the actual character in your string literal, or else know its constituent bytes in your desired encoding (in which case you could then use something like [`CHAR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_char)).

Comment: Putting the actual character (e.g. `REPLACE(SoName, '…', '')`) gives me `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file /Users/samuelbradshaw/Sites/praises/index.py on line 46, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`. Is there something I can do with that?
How do I "know its constituent bytes in [my] desired encoding"?

Comment: That takes us into the realms of Python... if you use your `\u0000` escape sequences in that realm, you'll be fine.  If you're not sure how to do that, I suggest you open a new question tagged [tag:Python] containing your Python code.

Answer (score 0):

I checked and its work with local environment but not work with Cluster Server.

`mysql  Ver 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`

```
 SELECT  `document_ref` , `title` 
   FROM `table_gpl13`  
  ORDER BY 
   REPLACE(title,'\u00e0','a'),    //à        
   REPLACE(title,'\u00e2','a'),    //â       
   REPLACE(title,'\u00e7','c'),    //ç             
   REPLACE(title,'\u00e8','e'),    //é            
   REPLACE(title,'\u00e9','e'),    //ê 
   REPLACE(title,'\u00fb','u')  ASC
```

Answer (score -2):

My brother told me to put this at the very top of the Python page that contains the MySQL query:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Everything seems to work now!